# как передать ответ на сервер через node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как правильно организовать код чтобы он только передовал данные.

И как его соединить с React приложением?
node js:

```
const http = require("http");
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "anime_db1",
    password: ""
  }).promise()
connection.connect(function(err){
      if (err) {
        return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
    }
})
connection.query('SELECT * FROM anime_full')
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})

http.createServer(function(request, response){
response.end()

}).listen(8000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так вернуть

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM anime_full')
  .then(data => {
    response.end(data)
  });


}).listen(8000)
```

Comment: Спасибо. И еще один вопрос, возможно ли в общем использовать 2 сервера на одном хосте? То есть, запустить на ноде сервер например на 8000 хосте и принимать реакт на 3000 и сделать между ними взаимодействие? Просто выдает ошибку при попытке так действовать.Хочу проверить верстку. Но не получается из-за ошибок.

Comment: Да действительно интересно. Даже и не пробовал. Если важно то опубликуйте вопрос. А если этот ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный. Галочка под стрелками